# Isn't the vote for a question to be "Opinion based" opinion based itself?

Tags: discussion, questions, opinion-based

I have asked the following question:

[Why does Kotlin compile faster than Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615947/why-does-kotlin-compile-faster-than-scala)

and it was closed as opinion based. According to me Kotlin indeed compiles faster and it's not an opinion but was admitted even by the language' creators.

On the other hand, the question:
[Why is compilation very slow for scala programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005124/why-is-compilation-very-slow-for-scala-programs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

was not closed as opinion based, but received very well instead.

Isn't in fact a for vote "Opinion based question" opinion based itself?

Comment: Your example (bad) question is too broad, not opinion based.

Comment: @Will I'd say both, really.  The first question in particular is rather unambiguously opinion based.  And the last question isn't actually as objective as  you might think, considering that speed isn't a single dimension for a computer program (often a program will do some operations faster and some slower, so which one is "faster" depends on the operations you need performed).

Answer (score 24):

Isn't *any* vote opinion based?

That's why we required 5 votes and not one to close a question (unless the user is a moderator).

Comment: This is the correct answer... In my opinion.

Comment: It's a fact that I voted on this post.

Comment: Re: *"unless the user is a moderator"*. What about dupe hammers?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - those are specifically for dupes, not for closing as "opinion based" (or any close reason that isn't dupe)

Answer (score -1):

This is because usually this kind of questions are really opinion based or highly prone to hypothesis. My guess is that the users who vote to close weren't aware of those objectives facts.

However, you can contest a close vote by asking in meta why it isn't like this.

In your case however, I won't vote for a reopenning, I think you have already your answer in the other link you provided.

Answer (score -3):

[Oded's already posted an adequate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338336/366904) to the Meta question that you are ostensibly asking here, so I won't belabor that.

Rather, it seems to me that you are just complaining about the closure of your question. And that's perfectly valid, so in the future, consider just asking about *that* on Meta, instead of calling the entire voting system into question.

To save you the work of opening a new Meta discussion, following is an analysis of the problems with [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615947/why-does-kotlin-compile-faster-than-scala), as it stands now. Rather than one, it actually asks *three* questions:

1. "How did they achieve that goal?"
2. "[W]hy is Scala compile time so slow that it was unacceptable for the Kotlin creators?"
3. "[W]hich features of the Scala compiler make it slower than the Kotlin compiler?"

Question #3 is rather broad; there might be a reasonable question buried in there somewhere, but you'll need to unpack it. Use the "edit" feature; this is what a closure is supposed to motivate.

Question #2 appears to be opinion based. However, this is mainly because of the reference to the opinions of the Kotlin creators. Without asking them, no one really knows what they consider "unacceptable" performance. Nor does it really matter. That said, once again, it seems to me that there might be a perfectly reasonable question buried here, and the presentation caused people to miss it. Perhaps consider asking why Scala's compile time is slower than Kotlin's compile time. That's an objective question that you could easily back up with facts, and it's something to which someone could provide a balanced, insightful, and technical answer (I imagine, although to be fair, I'm not knowledgeable about either of these technologies).

Question #1 is a completely valid question. Full stop. "How does Kotlin compile as quickly as Java?" is a perfectly valid question as far as I'm concerned, and if you had simply asked that as a standalone question, closure would have been inappropriate. Now, some might argue that this is rather broad, too, but so are lots of good questions. The general rule-of-thumb for "too broad" is whether you'd have to write an entire textbook to adequately answer the question, not *could* you write such a textbook on the topic. It seems to me that an expert on the Kotlin compiler/architecture could easily write a few paragraphs explaining how it achieves its performance goals.

As it stands, your question is borderline. I considered voting to reopen it, but the problems that I observed above kept me from casting a vote. I'll happily reconsider if you modify the question.

Comment: The whole reason that we close extremely broad questions is that we *don't* want people just posting a one paragraph summary of a few points related to a topic, while not actually answering the question.  It's not useful to have questions that just have the intro to a topic that takes a book to answer, and as such, don't actually answer the question.  Explaining how an entire language's compiler works, to explain why it's faster, is *textbook* too broad.

Comment: The other two questions are also *very* far off from being acceptable.  I doubt there's any way to make acceptable questions that could be reasonably considered edited forms of those questions.  Just attempting to assert that one compiler is faster than another is, in and of itself, not as objective as you seem to think (unless you specify a single program, or can demonstrate that it's faster for all programs), and explaining *why* it's faster and what contributes to that is also going to be quite subjective, and at the very least, ludicrously broad.

Comment: I didn't say "a one paragraph summary of a few points related to a topic". I believe it is possible to give a *complete answer* in a few paragraphs. Explaining the principles of a compiler or architecture that are key to its performance does not require an exhaustive treatise on the implementation. I've answered hundreds of questions that you *could* write a textbook on, yet can also be adequately answered with the most relevant information. I don't know, this seems pretty obvious to me. I *like* these kinds of questions because they keep the site from turning into a code-debugging service.

Comment: The fact that people find extremely broad questions *entertaining* is exactly why there is a close reason for them.  If they weren't so entertaining (despite not actually being productive or helpful) people wouldn't constantly be posting to/on them, and they wouldn't be a significant problem.  I *enjoy* questions like these too; but I recognize that they're not actually productive, when the scope is so large that the question is only ever summarizing what an answer would be, rather than *being* an answer.

Comment: I don't see any way to have a *complete* answer to a question of, "how is this compiler faster" in a few paragraphs.  You could describe which high level aspects of the compiler were changed, but even listing out all of the high level changes is likely to be many pages, and that's with no description of what's actually changed in them.

Comment: When I read people like Jonathan Shapiro writing about their compiler optimizations, it generally takes quite a few pages to get to the bottom of the issue, and not infrequently multiple blog posts, even if it's just a single subtopic! "Multiple blog posts" is, indeed, textbook Too Broad territory.

Comment: Perhaps I am overestimating the ability of the average answerer to be complete yet concise. It works perfectly well in my mind.